# imported link from database cut off at UTF8

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm inserting data into my database as a string.  The link column is latin1_swedish_ci.  I tried changing it to UTF8_swedish_ci (that didn't help).  I'm inserting a link and it gets inserted completely how it is.  I'm passing this link to a php file which is a popup and then outputting it on the screen.  During the output, if any of the links contain www.blahblah.com/somethingUTF8...there is more after UTF8 in the database but not on the screen.  Sorry for the long explanation...here's the code:

Inserting into DB:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $list){
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare ("INSERT INTO some_db (title, am_desc, link) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $title, $am_desc, $link);
    $title = $list->title;
    $am_desc = $list->description;
    $link = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $list->link);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();}
```

This is how I call the popup after running the mysqli_fetch_array to the the link:

```
<div style='position:relative; left:140px; padding-bottom:10px; 
width:100px'><a href='popup.php?link=".$link."' 
onClick='popup(this.href); return false;'>Click To Order</a></div>
```

And this is how I'm getting the code passed from the link in the popup:

```
$link = $_GET['link'];
```

It works for every link that does not have the UTF8.  I'm pretty new at this and the solution might be simple but I haven't been able to find it for hours.  Please help!

Comment: If you're binding $link to your prepared statement, why are you using mysqli_real_escape_string($link)?

Comment: Consider using urlencoding when echoing your $link value into your html

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm still learning mysqli, just switched from mysql queries. I just wanted to make sure it would add the the database.  It worked so I kept it there.

Comment: urlencode worked where I passed it in my href...thanks Mark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$link = utf8_encode($_GET['link']);` .....that should do the trick ;)